# How to use Go's net/http to distribute requests to Master-slave Databases based on Authentication?

Tags: mysql, http, go, cookies

Hello awesome Stackoverflow Community,

Apologies for the lame question. I was trying to find an answer to this question for some time, and googling didn't help me much.

I was playing around with Go's `net/http` package and was following [an article](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access) on organising `*sql.Db`

After going through it, I was trying to get two `*sql.Db`types, one for master and one for slave. My intention was, for a simple route `/home`, if the `session`cookie is already set, use the master connection and let the connection go to the master server and use an RW user, and if not, use the slave connection with an RO user. I already have a wrapper struct `DB` over `*sql.DB` and a CheckSessionCookie method attached to it.

```
func (d *DB) CheckSessionCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*http.Cookie) {
    c, err := r.Cookie("session")
    if err != nil {
    return nil
    }
    return c
}
```

My routes looks like

```
http.HandleFunc("/admin", envMaster.Admin) // Master connection's method
http.HandleFunc("/home", envSlave.Home) // Slave connection's method
```

However, I cannot think of an elegant way to use a different handler func if the request has a cookie already set. I was thinking, if I could read the cookie with a javascript and pass the cookie as a parameter, and use the route as

```
http.HandleFunc("/home", envMaster.Home)
http.HandleFunc("/home/:session", envSlave.Home)
```

But I am not sure if that is a good way to do it, especially if `http only` flag is set to the cookie.

How do I use a master connection if the request to "/home" has a session cookie already set?

Thank you.

Comment: One possible approach could be something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ij5Li7Pf7vc

Comment: Thank you @mkopriva, if you could add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You may look at it like this - each user could possibly have a different environment, and each environment has only connection type. So there are three types here that you could be dealing with - user, environment and connection. An environment could have a connection pool too, depending on what your problem complexity is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be something like this:

```
type Env struct {
    master *sql.DB
    slave *sql.DB
}

func (e *Env) DB(r *http.Request) *sql.DB {
    if _, err := r.Cookie("session"); err == http.ErrNoCookie {
            return e.slave
        }
        return e.master
}

func (e *Env) Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := e.DB(r)

    // ...
}
```

---

**NOTE:** *The following is a presonal opinion and therefore not really SO material.*

Although the example above may work for you, personally I think that tacking handlers on the `Env` type is a poor design decision. If you have a tiny app with 3, 5, or 10 routes it may be ok, but if you need to scale to more than that, say 50 routes, you end up with a single type that has 50+ methods and while the methods may depend on the environment it's not really obvious, at least to me, why the environment itself should have behaviour defined on it.

Then there's also the possibility of different handlers requiring different configuration types, or same configuration types but with different values, not only does `Env` now have 50+ methods it also has a multitude of fields that have little to nothing in common with each other. This also then allows a handler to touch stuff that it has no business touching.

In my opinion the `Env` type should at most comprise a set of values that represent the environment in which the application is gonna run and that's it, no behaviour, or at least no more than mere predicates and getters that actually make sense as being part of the environment.

Comment: Thank you. Since the said method can possibly result in a handler having 50+ methods, what else can be a good way? Is using a `/update` route with an `EnvMaster` handler that accepts POST requests only considered a good practice?

Comment: Personally, I would define handler types that better represent the "thing" that they are supposed to do, e.g. a `loginHandler` with just a single `ServeHTTP` method, or a `userHandler` with a set of `CRUD` methods that only deal with the `user` resource. Then these handler types would each have a field of type `*Env` to get access to the environment.

Comment: As far as the api design of the urls, I prefer to use HTTP methods to determine what action to take. Say you have the `userHandler` which implements the `http.Handler` interface with a `ServeHTTP` method and you've registered it under a single path, the `/users/` path. Now `ServeHTTP` would check an incoming request's HTTP method, whether it's GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE and based on that decide whether to retrieve a user(s), create a user, update a user, or delete a user.